# EFI boot from USB - drops to initramfs

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, initramfs

I have attempted to follow this guide:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative

It seems to have gotten partway through the boot process.

From OSX, the list of partitions on the boot device (I apologise for some serious potatocam):

[image: partition list]

Grub options after pressing 'edit' are here:

[image: grub options]

Initramfs prompt appears as follows:

[image]

The walkthrough suggests removing the internal hard disk of the laptop to do this procedure, but that is NOT an option for me. I only need to boot into this environment once, to perform an installation.

Further info - using OSX's diskinfo, I see the following UUIDs:

```
/dev/disk2s1 - C972F4B3-83FF-4E9F-A9CC-A7F0FDF6477D
/dev/disk2s2 - 44980794-0CC8-48FF-A1A4-902C6A781B7F
/dev/disk2s3 - BBFAD016-C4C4-4A70-9A44-4ED03CFB27B7
/dev/disk2s4 - D71A4E6A-014F-4F24-B54B-B3E70C5E753B
```

I think the largest partition, /dev/disk2s3, should probably be considered root? But changing the grub config to BBFA... does not help - the kernel cannot find that device. Also, it doesn't even load any partitions in /dev/sdb, only /dev/sdb itself.

Comment: What does lsblk -fm  show for your UUID?  The claim is ...10d9 does not exist.

Comment: I think it's true that that UUID didn't exist; however there appears to be a more severe problem. None of my partitions are getting loaded.

Comment: partition 1's UUID is not a FAT UUID, partition 2 should not even have a UUID,

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around this, though not really a direct fix. I ended up downloading the regular Ubuntu x64 installer, and using https://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/ ; then it was smooth sailing.